# Strange "memory" behaviour on AWS Lambda using with Node and Node-gyp

Tags: c, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda written in NodeJS the invocation process is pretty straightforward

NODEJS -> NodeModule(CPP) -> Extern C Function, this setup is compiled with node-gyp. 
You can see the entire code here at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-2d-CuY5fkwS3lwdE96R1V6NEk

The CPP node module invokes a function in C, that runs a loop. and increments two variables one in the scope of the C function and the other in main scope of the C code.

When you run this code locally. The loop increments and both the variables reach 11, as expected how much ever you run it. But when you run this same code in AWS Lambda, there is some sort of "memory" for each invocation. And the variable in the general scope, which is not getting reset is increasing, in multiples of 11, 22, 33 etc.

To repeat, this never happens locally, both the variables are always at 11.
you can build by running
1. node-gyp clean configure build
2. node app.js ( for local running)

Index.js is for AWS Lambda

I really cant explain this behavior? is there some sort of context or some sort of "memory" or caching that is available with Lambda?

I have made an Open API gateway for the same. (Feel free to refresh and see the "memory" in action).

https://koj2yva6z9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/testLambdaCache

This behavior is sometimes inconsistent, sometimes the count resets. Or you can reset by uploading new AWS lambda code.

Any thoughts on this strange behavior is appreciated.

**app.js (used for local testing)**

```
var addon = require('./build/Release/addon');
console.log(addon.testCache());
console.log(" addon method completed");
```

**index.js (used in lambda)**

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var addon = require('./build/Release/addon');
    var returnvalue=addon.testCache();
    console.log(returnvalue);
    console.log(" addon method completed");
    callback(null, "success::"+returnvalue);
}
```

**base.cc (wrapper for C code)**

```
#include <node.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

extern "C" char* testCache();

namespace demo {

    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::HandleScope;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Value;
    using v8::Exception;

    void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        cout << "C++ method started\n";
        char *returnStrings=NULL;
        returnStrings= testCache();
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,  returnStrings ));
    }

    void init(Local<Object> exports) {
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "testCache", Method);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(addon, init)

}
```

**decoder.c (c code running the loop)**

```
int tmpCounter=0;


char* testCache()
{
    int counter=0;
    printf("Local counter --> %d  Global Counter --> %d\n",counter,tmpCounter); 
    for(int i=0;i <10; i++)
    {
        counter = counter +1;
        tmpCounter = tmpCounter +1;
        //sleep(1);
    }
    printf("Local counter --> %d  Global Counter --> %d\n",counter,tmpCounter); 

    counter=counter+1;
    tmpCounter=tmpCounter+1;

    char strCounter[100];
    char strTmpCounter[100];
    snprintf(strCounter, 16, "%d", counter);

    snprintf(strTmpCounter, 16, "%d", tmpCounter);

    char *returnString=NULL;
    returnString=malloc(1000);

    strcat(returnString, "Count:");
    strcat(returnString, strCounter);
    strcat(returnString, " TmpCount:");
    strcat(returnString, strTmpCounter);
    strcat(returnString, "\0");
    printf("%s\n",returnString);
    fflush(stdout);
    return returnString;

}
```

Comment: Post your code. You cannot share your gdrive with the world...BTW I can guess: local scoped var is declared without initialization, I mean: `int local_val;` So [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: there are multiple files, is there a better way to share it other than google drive?

Comment: Take a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Start posting the [tag:c] function with the loop.

Comment: thankyou i have added the minimal code here as well.

Answer (score 2):

> is there some sort of context or some sort of "memory" or caching that is available with Lambda?

I wouldn't say it's "available," in the sense that it is predictable or consistent, because you should not design around it, but yes, there is container reuse.

To see this in action:

Create a uuid, or random number, or something like that, and store it in a global variable outside your handler.  Then, inside the handler, log it.  You'll see that the same process or group of processes (as identified by the uuid) will likely, but not necessarily, handle subsequent requests that are close together in time.

> Let’s say your function finishes, and some time passes, then you call it again. Lambda may create a new container all over again [...]
>
> However, if you haven’t changed the code and not too much time has gone by, Lambda may reuse the previous container. This offers some performance advantages to both parties: Lambda gets to skip the nodejs language initialization, and you get to skip initialization in your code. Files that you wrote to /tmp last time around will still be there if the sandbox gets reused.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: i understand container reuse. but why is the code still in context. if the same code is run locally, the value gets reset. If run locally it does imply that its being indefinily reused container. In this case not only the container is being reused, i feel that the code never left the context.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Here's a question.  Locally, do two iterations interact? `var addon = require('./build/Release/addon'); console.log(addon.testCache()); var addon2 = require('./build/Release/addon');
console.log(addon2.testCache());`

Comment: yes if i use to instances of addon in my code then that is expected, but if you look at the initializer in lambda, the handler is instantiating the object addon (so that is not globally instantiated). so each time when the handler is called the addon should be freshly instantiated as i understand.

Answer (score 0):

All call to `strcat` into `testCache` are [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of `malloc`ated memory is not inited.

Change it using [calloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)

```
returnString=calloc(1, 1000);
```

or change the first one with `sprintf`

```
sprintf(returnString, "Count:");
```

Moreover `strcat(returnString, "\0");` is useless

Finally always check malloc & friend returned value, e.g.

```
if (returnString != NULL)
{
   // OK, MEMORY ALLOCATED
}
else
{
   // ERROR
}
```

Comment: What i am looking for is the reason why the "int tmpCounter=0;" is not getting reset and "int counter=0;"  is getting reset every time i initiate lambda call. 

This same code when executed locally gets both counters reset

I am aware of other small issues which can be fixed.

Comment: @sandeepzgk Why spend time to check an undefined behavior code? Correct your undefined and retest it, so we'll continue checking for other things.